# Knockout - save state with amplify

Tags: object, knockout.js, save, state, observable

I'm wondering if Amplify can easily handle big data model with lots of nested knockout observable objects.
The goal is to save and restore current state of the data (view) model after page refresh.

From few examples seems that every observable needs to be extended to use local store.
Probably that can be applied globaly, but I'm not sure how will the nested observable objects behave.
(ie. viewModel has many observable variables and each of them holds json objects with more observable variables etc.).
Is it possible to save the state of the viewModel so that after page refresh all nested observables are restored in a proper way?
(Another problem could be performance as it has to be used on the mobile devices)

Does anyone has any experience with these kind of issues?

Comment: You could use the mapping plugin to serialise/deserialize the view model to JSON, then store that string using amplify. Check out http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/plugins-mapping.html

Answer (score 1):

This can be done and I am doing it. Though I have split it up as separate modules that handles my ajax calls and caching.

One this to note, if you store and entire knockout viewmodel with observables, when fetching it back, the data will not be restored. This is because your observables are functions and not data itself.

In order to this, you will have to convert your observable view model to proper Javascript objects (ko.toJS or ko.mapping.toJS if using mapping plugin) and then store it. When you retrieve the data, you have to send it through your viewmodel to recreate the observables.

This is not as costly as you think. Using the mapping plugin it is pretty easy to do this. But if there is huge amount of data in your array then you should rethink getting that much amount of data, particulary for a mobile device.